# How can I access the mysql community server in terminal or by GUI?

Tags: mysql, macos

I downloaded the '[MySQL Community Server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)' and installed it on my macOS (10.13.6).

How can I access the MySLQ Community Server?  Where is it? I can only find that there is a new mySQL pane in the 'system preference'.

The terminal shows me: command not found as below:

> $mysql
>
> -bash: mysql: command not found

I'm new about this. Is the right usage of mySQL by GUI is firstly install the 'mySQL Community Server' and then install the 'MySQL Workbench'?

Comment: is the mysql command in your PATH?

Comment: when you type the command 'mysql', the terminal should understand where to find  the mysql program. For this, it will refer to PATH. Try adding the location of 'bin' folder of mysql installation to PATH and restart the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the MySQL server (MySQL Community Server) can work with terminal. Use the `mysql` command in terminal after the path of mysql (`/usr/local/mysql/bin`) has been added into PATH(modify the '~/.bash_profile' file for instance).

If one needs GUI, download a MySQL Workbench, and let it connect to the MySQL Server. The operations done by commands in the terminal can be done via the UI of MySQL Workbench.